# Apriori Algorithm shows lots of result even for small amount of data

Tags: python, machine-learning, apriori

I am trying out apriori algorithm which takes more than the expected time, this is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)
transactions = []

for i in range(0, 10):
    temp = []
    for j in range(0, 20):
        temp.append(str(dataset.values[i,j]))
    transactions.append(temp)
  
from apyori import apriori
associations = apriori(transactions, min_support=0.03, min_confidence=0.7, min_lift=3, min_length=2)

result = list(associations)
```

it's working fine upto the point of creating apriori object. But when I tried to run the last line (conversion to list) it's taking huge amount of time.

As you can see above I have only inputted 10 transactions, but it has output more than a million rules, so I couldn't find the error in the code. pls help me to find the issue.

The below image shows my variable values in anaconda spyder ide.
[image]

Thank you.....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Please hard-code your data frame into the posted program.  We certainly aren't going to type in your CSV file by hand.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

change `min_support` to `min_support=0.003` and  `min_confidence` to `min_confidence=0.2`

If the problem is not resolved, check out `apriori.py`.